# Get macOS default browser name - LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForContentType

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, default, nsurl

I am developing a macOS application in Xcode. One of the things I need to do, is to open URL's the system detault web browser. I have an alert that pops up that gives the user this option. The alert is supposed to show the name of the default web browser. However I am unable to figure out the name of the default web browser.

I have the tried the following code:

```
NSLog(@"%@", LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForContentType(kUTTypeURL, kLSRolesAll, nil));
```

It just returns `file:///Applications/Opera.app/` even though my default browser is set to Safari. Not matter what I change my default browser to (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, etc...), the above method just returns the URL for Opera browser.

Does anyone know how I can find out what the name of the default browser is? I know how to open URL's in the default browser, thats very easy, but getting the name of the default browser isn't.

I know this is possible because apps like Tweetbot, have an option saying "Open in Safari" which changes to whatever you default browser is.

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] open:url]` to open any URL in the default browser and `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] URLForApplicationToOpenURL: url]` to get the URL for the default application for a given URL.

To get the app name, try `[[NSBundle bundleWithURL:appUrl] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"]` or `[[NSBundle bundleWithURL:appUrl] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleName"]` if the first is null. If both fail, `[appUrl deletingPathExtension] lastPathComponent]` can be used as a last resort.

See the docs here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1533463-openurl?language=objc

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1533391-urlforapplicationtoopenurl?language=objc

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle/1408696-objectforinfodictionarykey?language=objc

Comment: Thanks and very close, but not quite there. I had to use ```[[[NSBundle bundleWithURL:test] infoDictionary] valueForKey:@"CFBundleExecutable"]``` to get the name. Your method didn't work.

Comment: Although the NSWorkspace approach is what I needed, so thanks very much.

Comment: `CFBundleExecutable` will return the executable filename, which may not be the same as the displayed application name. Also, the app name may be localized, and `CFBundleExecutable` isn't. You should try `CFBundleName` or `CFBundleDisplayName`. I'll update my answer with the latest, since it's the only required one of the two. You can find other relevant keys here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html

Comment: Ah good point, I will use ```CFBundleName``` as ```CFBundleDisplayName``` return ```null```.

Comment: Remember that different browsers might have different values set on Info.plist… The safest would be to check both keys and use whichever is set.

Comment: Good point and if both return null, then I will simply state "Open in Default Browser".

Answer (score 2):

Try the other LaunchServices method `LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForURL` and pass the `http` scheme

```
CFURLRef httpURL = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("http://"), NULL);
NSLog(@"%@", LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForURL(httpURL, kLSRolesAll, nil));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44778202/4691224) on Swift 5

```
var defaultBrowser: String? {
    NSWorkspace.shared.urlForApplication(toOpen: URL(string: "http://")!)
        .flatMap(Bundle.init(url:))
        .flatMap {
            $0.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleDisplayName") ?? $0.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleName")
        }.flatMap {
            $0 as? String
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//given a fileUrl
CFURLRef helperApplicationURL = LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForURL((__bridge CFURLRef)fileUrl, kLSRolesAll, NULL);
    if (helperApplicationURL != NULL) {
        NSString *helperApplicationPath = [(__bridge NSURL *)helperApplicationURL path];
        NSString *helperApplicationName = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] displayNameAtPath:helperApplicationPath];
        CFRelease(helperApplicationURL);
        if ([helperApplicationName containsString:@".app"]) {
            helperApplicationName = [helperApplicationName stringByDeletingPathExtension];
        }
        return helperApplicationName;
    }
```